# Asynchronous method to convert voice to text using google speech api in php?

Tags: php, google-speech-api

I am trying to convert big voice flac files into text using google's api, but it is getting timed out because of its size, can we upload flac files from server to google's account or bucket using php?

I am following this documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/async-recognize#speech-async-recognize-gcs-php

But i would like to know..how can i upload my large flac files there on the bucket?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can firstly upload the audio files to the Google Cloud Storage bucket, and provide the file path in Google Cloud Storage like `gs://` to the api to transcribe.

This webpage may be useful:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample